# Make Seeder for Specific Values

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I'm using a seeder in Laravel. I have a table called `nationalities` that has two columns: `id` and `name.` I want to seed more than one record with specific unique values (German, French, etc.).

**NationalitySeeder.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Nationality;

class NationalitySeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $nation = Nationality::create([
            'name' => 'american'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /** Seed the application's database **/

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(NationalitySeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: Read on 'Factories'.

Answer (score 1):

Answer updated for Laravel 8.x.

`database/seeders/NationalitySeeder.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Nationality;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class NationalitySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $nationalities = ['German', 'French'];

        Nationality::factory()
            ->count(count($nationalities))
            ->sequence(fn ($sequence) => ['name' => $nationalities[$sequence->index]])
            ->create();
    }
}
```

`database/factories/NationalityFactory.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class NationalityFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            // the following default value is overwritten by NationalitySeeder
            'name' => $this->faker->languageCode(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a factory file in `database/factories` called NationalityFactory.php
containing the following code:

```php
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Nationality::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->languageCode,
    ];
});
```

In NationalitySeeder.php put the following code

```php
$nationalities = ['German', 'French', 'etc.'];

factory(App\Nationality::class, count($nationalities))
           ->create()
           ->each(function ($nationality, $key) use ($nationalities) {
                $nationality->name = $nationalities[$key];
            });
```

This will make nationalities based on how many you have configured in the array using Laravel factories.

Comment: it gives me an error : Undefined variable: nationalities

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell that i updated my answer to use $nationalities. Did this work for you ?